# Binding items to ComboBox from JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, wpf, list, data-binding, combobox

I need to change below method:

```
public static IList<SomeItem> GetProjects() {
 List<SomeItem> projects = new List<SomeItem>();    
 string result = Task.Run(() => TestMethodAsync("getProjects",GetApiKeyAsync())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
 MyObject resultparsed = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyObject>(result);

  foreach (SomeItem item in resultparsed.result.items)
  {
   projects.Add(item);
  }
  return projects;
}
```

that items will be automaticly adding to `ComboBox`:

This is from **XAML**:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

And here I'm trying to modify above code **C#:**

```
public List<string> ProjectList { get; internal set; }
public static IList<SomeItem> GetProjects()
{
 ProjectList = new List<string>;//???

 string result = Task.Run(() => TestMethodAsync("getProjects",GetApiKeyAsync())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
 MyObject resultparsed = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyObject>(result);

  foreach (SomeItem item in resultparsed.result.items)
  {
    ProjectList.Add(item);//??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `List<string>` with an `ObservableCollection<string>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ProjectList { get; internal set; }
```

Unlike a `List<T>`, an `ObservableCollection<T>` provides notifications to the UI when items get added or removed.

You could then populate the source collection something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ProjectList { get; internal set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public async Task PopiuateProjectListAsync()
{
    ProjectList.Clear();
    MyObject resultparsed = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string result = TestMethodAsync("getProjects", GetApiKeyAsync());
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyObject>(result);
    });

    foreach (SomeItem item in resultparsed.result.items)
    {
        ProjectList.Add(item.SomeStringProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what about GetProjects method? can show me how to correct modify it?

Comment: I guess SomeItem has some string property that you wan to display in the ComboBox?

Comment: ProjectList.Clear & Add I have the same error: "an object reference is required for the non-static field...."

Comment: Sorry, the PopiuateProjectListAsync() method should be be static. I modified this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178506/discussion-between-4est-and-mm8).